# How to use all the common dependencies of one common project into another project by adding common project as jar

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven, dependency-management

I have a common java project which has multiple dependencies in pom.xml. Now whichever dependencies are added in common same dependencies I want to use in another project when I import the common project.

For example, a common project has spring-MVC, hibernate, and many other dependencies. Now I also need hibernate and spring-mvc dependencies in my child project where common is added as a jar.
As my common project already has the required dependencies downloaded and it is there as part of my jar file.
Now I want to use those dependencies without adding them to the child project.

Comment: My current problem is that I have multiple projects where common is being added as dependency and for all these projects all the required dependencies are being downloaded and when I get a final war file its size is quite huge.

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand the question. If A depends on B and B on C, then will automatically be added to the classpath because it is a transitive dependency.

Answer (score 0):

Add the the project(which has all common dependency) as parent in your child project pom. so you wont have to add them in

```
<parent>
    <groupId>com.xxxxx.xxx</groupId>
    <artifactId>your-parent-project</artifactId>
    <version>snapshot id of parent project</version>
    <relativePath/> 
</parent>
```

Answer (score 0):

What I understood, you want to include a common artifact but that brings it its own dependencies as well. To avoid this, you can exclude the undesired artifacts while adding a maven dependencies like below

```
<dependencies>
<dependency>
  <groupId>sample.ProjectB</groupId>
  <artifactId>Project-B</artifactId>
  <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <exclusions>
    <exclusion>
      <groupId>sample.ProjectD</groupId> <!-- Exclude Project-D from Project-B -->
      <artifactId>Project-D</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
  </exclusions>
</dependency>
```

See more here [Dependency Exclusions](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-optional-and-excludes-dependencies.html#dependency-exclusions)